# Change Action Bar Overflow Icon in an app

Tags: android, icons, overflow, action

I am trying to change the Action Bar Overflow Icon in an app.  I have seen some info on this site but it's not clear to me.  Does anyone know what code I should enter and in what files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change the `Overflow Icon` programmatically by using `Toolbar.setOverflowIcon()` method.

```
// ToolBar
Toobar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setOverflowIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_overflow_icon));
}
```

**Toolbar XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

or, you can also define a `style` for custom `Overflow Icon` in your main `styles.xml` like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/your_overflow_icon</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The first one worked for me by removing the 'If (Toolbar ...) line.  So I used the first, third, and 4th lines of the code you suggested.  It worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Good to know that it works. If you get any help from anyone's  answer and if you think answer is useful then its better to give an upvote and accept the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this may be helpful to you

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_title);
......
}
```